# Add drain line to existing Island fixture vent?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, drain-waste-vent

In CA, would code allow for a drain line to be tied into the vent line shown at the location of the red arrow below?

Single family home.

Happy to draw a picture of where that vent lines goes, if that makes a difference.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_fixture_vent

Comment: are you wanting to put another drain in the island, or does the vent pipe just conveniently happen to be where you want to add a drain?

Comment: Not likely. The vent is there to provide air to the island sink drain, draining through the vent compromises that.

Comment: the vent pipe just conveniently happens to be where i want to add a drain

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add a new drain to the vent stack. That would compromise the function of the vent.

To add another drain in to your plumbing system, you have to make sure that the waste line and vent are large enough for the fixture.